# Drop Role Not Dropping Though Role Name Exists

Tags: postgresql

I have two users `Jason` and `postgres`. Since I just started learning this, I have no idea why this code is not working. All I'm trying to do is drop an user, but am unable too. What's wrong with my code?

```
postgres=# DROP OWNED BY Jason;
ERROR:  role "jason" does not exist
postgres=# \du
                             List of roles
 Role name |                   Attributes                   | Member of 
-----------+------------------------------------------------+-----------
 Jason     | Superuser, Create role, Create DB, Replication | {}
 postgres  | Superuser, Create role, Create DB, Replication | {}
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Case sensitivity.

```
DROP OWNED BY "Jason";
```

PostgreSQL *is* case sensitive, it just lower-cases unquoted identifiers. To preserve case, "double quote" identifiers.

Comment: @jason328: So don't use double quotes and identifiers are case insensitive. I would *never* use a mixed-case user name to begin with. Never.

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter: AFAIK some of the MS frameworks require (or practically require) it due to local conventions combined with schema auto-discovery. I'm pretty sure I've come across this sort of thing 'round here before but I can't claim personal experience.

Comment: @muistooshort: Well, if you have to, you just have to. Luckily, I don't. :)

Comment: @muistooshort That's bizarre, but fits with other oddities in case handling in MS products like the way NTFS is case sensitive but the win32 file APIs aren't (http://support.microsoft.com/kb/100625).

Answer (score 2):

You should follow couple of things while remove the user

First ,Should check and remove the database which are `owned` by the user

```
 DROP OWNED By "Jason" ;    // remove database objects owned by a database role
```

Next can drop the role of the  user by

```
 DROP ROLE "Jason";
```